# Pass an object file from view to template in Django using Ajax

Tags: ajax, django, object, view, django-templates

I am trying to pass an object file (3d object) from a view to a html template using Ajax. 
Here is the basic code in the view:

```
def guiMesh(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.is_ajax():

         obj = pywavefront.Wavefront( "test.obj")

         context = {'meshObj': obj}

return render(request, 'template.html', context)
```

here is the code the template

```
 $.ajax({
        url : '', // the endpoint,commonly same url
        type : "POST", // http method
        data : { csrfmiddlewaretoken: csrftoken, cooVertex: cooVertex }, 
               success : function(dataObj) {

                        console.log("dataObj " + dataObj.size)
      })
```

The view side seems working as it does not give any error, but the template side seems not receiving the file correctly. Where am I doing wrong?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: To return object with ajax from view you need a JsonResponse , look in the django docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/request-response/  about JsonResponse